# What is EMC recommended circuit and is it necessary?

Tags: power-supply, emc

I'm building a power supply with five isolation dc-dc converters, here is their data sheet https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pdqe15-d.pdf

The data sheet mentions a EMC recommended circuit, below a simpler version of the circuit, see below.

Is the EMC circuit necessary? I'm not going to be subjecting the power supply to any magnetic fields.

[image]

Comment: "I'm not going to be subjecting the power supply to any magnetic fields." That's not how EMC works... your part must co-exist with any other EMC compliant device on the market. It's not just immunity you need to consider, but also radiated emissions.

Comment: Btw don't mix up the bulk cap with the decoupling/filter caps. In figure 3, C0 and C4 are bulk caps to make up for power variations, the rest of them are filter or decoupling caps. You'll definitely want the bulk caps, as seen on every other power supply ever made. At what extent you need filters, it's hard to say. The two filter caps in figure 2 make the transformer coil form a "pi filter" together with them, which is a generally nice thing when it comes to EMC.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the different caps I totally would've mixed them up. Is there any particular cap that works best for this type of thing? Ceramic vs polarized for example

Comment: Not unless ESR matters. Ceramic SMD is cheapest so go with that if you can find it with the value you need, though mind the voltage rating, apparently 50V or 100V in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 'EMC circuit' is simply a passive filter to avoid propagating switching noise upstream on the power line. Search for "common mode input filter" for details.

For various reasons (entire books have been written on the subject) the DC/DC converter generates electric noise. If it in not suitably suppressed (as in 'recommended because we think it is suitable', not always true) the power cable will radiate noise causing troubles (and an EMC test failure)

If you are doing a one shot circuit for yourself it is not critical, for commercial product it's quite important because such a failure could lead to product recalls.

Comment: This circuit isn't exactly one shot it's for a school project. I'm building a guitar pedal power supply so I do need to limit noise. The EMC would keep excessive noise from the output but I'm also using a linear regulator just before the outputs, to reduce DC ripple, would the EMC still than be necessary to reduce noise?

Comment: The filter is mostly for HF noise propagating *upwards* toward the source. However it will help even for noise *after* the regulator (which can't reduce it over the loop bandwidth regulation frequency). So if you can fit it, it's a good idea

Answer (score 4):

It's purpose is for reducing conducted RF emmissions for Electro-Magnetic Compliance (EMC) purposes.

Basically if you want to pass compliance testing (e.g. CE mark, UL, etc), it may help reduce noise levels conducted out of your device onto the mains or DC power input.

Whether or not it is necessary is for you to determine. But if you have the space, I'd include it.

Comment: Since it has *five* of them, at least a bigger one is IMHO needed

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio That one is a bulk cap for power stability, it serves a different purpose.

Comment: I've always heard EMC stands for electromagnetic compatibility.

Comment: @Hearth either/or. Its one of those acronyms that gets used interchangably.